# How to ensure Networkstream reads all data before returning C#

Tags: c#, sockets, byte, networkstream

Im currently working on a bit of a sideproject which communicates with NASA JPL to get data about the solar system. Im bascially new to anything network related and Im having some problems understanding how to Read a networkstream correctly.

This code is what i've been able to piece together which technically works however its not really reliable. The problem with is that if you send commands to frequently i often cant read the response, and with higher ping internet its seems almost impossible to get any response at all.

I have tried to solve this with researching beginread or asyncread, but its really out of my knowledge level.

I realise that what i need to do is for the code to wait for a response before actually reading everything and then returning the message recieved. If anyone can help to get me on the way it would be greatly appriciated :)

```
 public void ServerSocket(string ip, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to server.");
            today = DateTime.Now;
            tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect to server");
            return;
        }

        //Assign networkstream
        networkStream = client.GetStream();

        //start socket read/write thread
        readWriteThread = new Thread(readWrite);
        readWriteThread.Start();

    }

    private void readWrite()
    {
        string command, recieved;
        bool title = false;

        //Read first thing given
        recieved = JplRead();
        Console.WriteLine(recieved);

        //Set up connection loop
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Response: ");
            command = Console.ReadLine();


            if (command == "exit")
                break;

            JplWrite(command);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            recieved = JplRead();

            Console.WriteLine(recieved);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from server");
        networkStream.Close();
        client.Close();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Converts message string into bytes and then sends them to JPL
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    public void JplWrite(string message)
    {
        message += Environment.NewLine;
        byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        networkStream.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
        networkStream.Flush();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads network stream, has a buffer of 1024 bytes but reads all data through networkStream.DataAvailable
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string JplRead()
    {
        byte[] data= new byte[1024];
        StringBuilder recieved = new StringBuilder();

        int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

        // Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size, therefore reads all available data through this loop before stitching it togheter. 
        do
        {
            numberOfBytesRead = networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            recieved.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
        }
        while (networkStream.DataAvailable);

        return recieved.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem: You are doing Ping-Pong. So if anything goes out of step, your are stuck. You can avoid that by doing the reads (and those, only) on the thread while waiting for user input on your main thread and sending from there. If you feel ready for a challenge you could also try TPL (async / await).

Comment: How do you know when a message ends?

Comment: @Fildor hmm yeah i thought about that, do you got any usable examples ?

Comment: I haven't got a usable example out of the box. Since you are using cmd line it's not that easy, neither. I don't know that API. Can it send messages without having received request before? If so, I'd probably start off by setting up one separate thread, that does the reading, only (and output to console). It would probably be easier to make a simple GUI, so you can easily separate in- and output.

Comment: @Fildor Solved it this weekend, seperating the read/write was the solution, thank you for your input :)